# what can I do to make display the bin folder on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

can anyone help me solve the issue that I have ?
in fact when I create a project on eclipse, the bin folder doesn't display and I am able to create a javadoc for my project. I need help please.

Comment: I have only managed to do it in Project Explorer, but never in Package Explorer.

Answer (score 41):

I don't know what the reason for your question but you can see the bin directory in **Project Explorer** (not **Package Explorer**). Here you click the triangle and select *Customize View...* and remove the click on *Java output folders*

[image]

Comment: So to be more specific I would like to know how to install eclipse and JDK because maybe it is because I am not able to tell eclipse where to read the JDK

Comment: where do you "click the triangle"?

Comment: @amphibient (might be too late, but for everyone else..) 
when you open the "Project Explorer" view, you can see the "triangle" (also known as "View Menu") next to the "Minimize" and "Maximize" buttons. Click on that and you will see the "Customize View" option :)

Answer (score 4):

To change this behaviour and hide the “.class” files you need to do the following.

1. Find your class output folder in the “Project explorer” window. This is usually called “bin” or “target” for Maven projects
2. Right-click this folder and click “Properties”
3. Tick the “Derived” checkbox and click “OK”

“.class” files will now be hidden in future.

*Source: http://ayubmalik.co.uk/2011/12/hide-class-files-when-opening-a-type-or-resource-in-eclipse-ide/*

Answer (score 2):

If your Eclipse version doesn't allow you to show "Java Output Folders" as mentioned by nanda, then try the Navigator View (From the main menu: Window > Show View > Navigator). The Navigator View shows the bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit vague but try right clicking on the project and choosing build path, and see if the output directory for your java classes is set to bin. It may not appear in your unless you add some Java source code

Comment: So to be more specific I would like to know how to install eclipse and JDK because maybe it is because I am not able to tell eclipse where to read the JDK

Comment: when I create a project on eclipse, the bin folder doesn't display and I am not able to create a javadoc for my project. I need help please.