# How do I make the default bin directory visible in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what can I do to make display the bin folder on eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163923/what-can-i-do-to-make-display-the-bin-folder-on-eclipse)

I know this is a **searing** duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163923/what-can-i-do-to-make-display-the-bin-folder-on-eclipse) question, however the answer supplied in that question does not work for me or help me in the least bit.

I am trying to get my project's default output folder (`bin/`) to be visible in the Project Explorer view, and I can't seem to figure out how. When I right-click my project (inside Project Explorer), I don't see any option that says "**Available Configurations**" or "**Customize View**". I'm using Indigo 3.7 Java EE.

Thanks for any help here. And, if someone can point out how that answer *does* answer this question, I will gladly delete this "duplicate" myself.

**Edit** here is what I' seeing:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* I want this? Why *wouldn't* I want fine-grain control over all the folders in my project?!? Why does everybody think Eclipse is doing you some huge favor by hiding/filtering the `bin/` directory for you? The very fact that you even asked that question, combined with the default nature of Eclipse, combined with that being the general disposition of all Eclipse programmers has me absolutely **stunned**.

Comment: SO: "Come ask questions about soda." Me: "I need help drinking soda!" Dave: "Why would you drink soda?!?!"

Comment: Go ahead--be stunned. But recognize that sometimes knowing *why* somebody wants something can lead to an alternative solution to getting what you want. Calm down, holy crap. *lol* Good luck.

Comment: Oh, it's "doing you a favor" because there's no reason to have a view into a folder that is 100% generated, can disappear at any time, etc. You can see it from the command line, the explorer, the "navigation" view, or the project explorer if you un-select the java output folders as in the question you link to. You don't get there by "right clicking the project", you get there from the view's dropdown menu, the arrow at the top right of the view. I'm stunned you couldn't follow the directions in the question you linked to.

Comment: You'll also need to uncheck the ".class resources" option. It's the one with the checkbox next to the phrase ".class resources".

Comment: Where is this .class resource option?

Comment: ... The same place as the Java output folders option. They're in alphabetical order. Or you can narrow by typing something in the filter text input.

Comment: I only see a Build, Compiling, Packaging and Documenting section under Project Properties, absolutely **no** references to a .class resources section!

Comment: Please see my edit (attached screen shot)

Comment: "Project Properties" has nothing to do with this, as both the question you link to, and my comment above, states. These are *view* customization options, reached by clicking the little arrow ("triangle" in the linked question) in the [upper right corner of the *view*](http://imgur.com/MWx0d) and choosing the "Customize View" option.

Comment: Oh, regarding this being the "general disposition of all Eclipse programmers"--I don't really use Eclipse, so you'll need to come up with another reason why I asked. I'd suggest things like "curious because it's essentially never useful", or "maybe there actually *is* a reason, but said reason can be better-satisfied in a different way", etc.

Comment: But there is not triangle just a Projects, Services and Files section. Also, of what better/different way do you speak?

Comment: Dude, I gave you a freakin' screenshot of the little arrow. Without doing a screen cast I can't make it any clearer than I already have. Nothing anyone said has talked about project properties at all, and I've said, explicitly and twice, as much. Consider doing some Eclipse tutorials so when people use Eclipse terminology you know what they're talking about. As I said, *how* may depend on *why*, which you refuse to elucidate.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have this project due for a client on *Monday* and I need to get the compiled class files so I can zip them up like a jar and send them off. Thats why this is so urgent.

Comment: For a ***client***?! Now I *am* stunned. You're telling me you're *billing* somebody for doing Java work, and you're not able to the &*!@&# command line and jar up some class files? Or use Eclipse's freakin' "Export to Jar" function which does exactly what you want, without needing to see the `bin` directory? (See? Don't need to see the `bin` directory. NOW do you understand why I asked?????)

Comment: Well it needs to be a jar, but I read that a jar is basically just a zip file, so I just need to get at the class files, put them in a folder, zip the folder, and then rename it with a jar extension instead of zip.

Comment: You are clearly in way over your head. I told you how to get the `bin` directory to be visible (unnecessary, as predicted). I told you there's an "Export to Jar" option. I told you you could just jar up the files from the command line. You sort-of know a jar is a zip file--guess what that means? `bin` is a freakin' folder--zip it up from Explorer, or the equivalent in whatever OS you're using. And hope that you don't need any of the options doing an actual `jar` operation provides. And hope you don't have any external library dependencies.

Comment: Don't you think I would have tried that already!!!! But not only will Eclipse *not* let me see `bin` inside Project Explorer, it won't even let me Send To >> Compressed File (Zip). What a piece of junk!

Comment: "Explorer or the equivalent in whatever OS you're using." In other words, a freakin' file browser, which every OS has. Or use the Eclipse jar export. Or jar them from the command line. How can you possibly not be able to look at the screen shot I provided and not see the arrow? (It's the triangle with the big red arrow pointing to the big red circle around the arrow.) Not that you need to do that anyway. This is NOT an issue with Eclipse, it is an issue with *you*.

Comment: Dave, Although I appreciate your help, I don't think you're *reading* my comments.I don't want to export a jar! Unrelated, but just for thoroughness, I then need to get that jar "deployed" as a "bean" on an "application server" (not my terminology, I'm just reading the RFP). But I can't do any of that until I have the jar. And I can't do that until I figure out this `bin` problem. I can't use the "Eclipse jar export" function, because *I don't have a jar to begin with!!!*

Comment: You don't want to export a jar--you just want to get all your compiled class files into a jar. And thaaaat's what "export to jar" does. Despite having already told you how to make the `bin` directory visible (which isn't necessary), and telling you that there are other ways to do it that don't even involve Eclipse, you don't even use the tool Eclipse *provides* to do precisely what you want. So you now have at least three different ways to get at those class files--yet somehow none of them are what you want. And I'm the one not reading the comments? Hysterical.

Comment: Dave - the RFP says to use Eclipse. If I don't follow the RFP I could be in violation of my contract. I'm not a genius like you are, I'm just a down-on-his-luck-kind-of-guy with a few C++ classes under his belt trying to provide for his family. Any actual **help** here is appreciated, but we are getting nowhere fast here.

Comment: I GAVE YOU A SCREENSHOT OF WHERE THE VIEW OPTIONS MENU IS! There's no way to tell how a jar file is made anyway. I gave you an option to use Eclipse without having to perform the seemingly-magical steps of enabling the view of the `bin` folder--which, as I said, is already available in the Navigation view ANYWAY. We're not getting nowhere "fast" at all, you've managed to completely ignore every single thing I've said that would allow you to solve your problem for 2+ hours.

Comment: [Here's the screen shot again.](http://imgur.com/MWx0d) Make clicky on the thing in the big red circle (in your Eclipse, not on the screenshot). Choose "Customize view". Unselect "Java output folders" (as in the question you linked to). Unselect "*.class resources". There. `bin` folder. Useless. Right click on your project. "Export..." Java. Jar file. Or type "jar" in the filter. Decide what to put in it. Now you have a jar file. Still using Eclipse. As mentioned several comments above.

Comment: I wish I could downvote this more.

Comment: Dave thank you for your steadfastdness and for staying with me here. I sense you are frustrated with me but I think I really learned something today.

Comment: Good job on the sensing part, at least.

Comment: Working with Maven defined output folders, if your Eclipse Juno project defines a output folder that happens to match a Maven output directory, Eclipse annoyingly hides it from you and provides no option to un-hide it.  At least on a Maven type of project, Eclipse should allow forcing the output dir to be visible in the case that it is hidden by Eclipse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dude - you're in **NetBeans** (at least thats the screenshot). You need to download [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and use that instead...

Comment: OMG **thank you!!!!** Thank you!!! I thought I was losing my dang mind there for a few hours.

Comment: *giggling* Wow. Hope the client doesn't see all this.

Comment: Ecipse Juno does not allow you to un-filter the hidden "bin" directory.  I don't see how this would be a solution to the original question.

Answer (score 6):

Use the navigator view. Its your actual file system not a generated view of it. You are seeing the bin directory but eclipse is parsing stuff out and putting it in "different" spots.

Window>views>other, type "nav" and you'll see it.

Edit: now that I've read the comments between you and dave newton I see that he was right in asking why you wanted to see it because you're not asking the right questions.
Yes. Export to jar does what you need. Try it. Rename to .zip and open it and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might help :

1. Right Click your `Project`, go to `Properties`.
2. Select `Java Build Path` from Left Hand Side.
3. On the Right Hand Side, Select `Source Tab`.
4. Click on `Add Folder`, and mark the checkbox for `bin` as `SELECTED` under `Source Folder Selection` Window.
5. Press OK and OK again. And you will see your `bin` Folder.

Now you can see your bin folder, in `Project Explorer`.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to use the core Java toolchain: java, javac and jar at least, because then you can never be held hostage by a misbehaving or confusing IDE.

However, once you're familiar with those tools moving up to maven will help too, as those tools are annoying if you find yourself typing out a long classpath. Maven can be run from the command line or within your IDE, and can build the jar you need.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting it in the project view is importing your workspace back into the project.  This is not desirable but if you must have the bin it will definitely work.  I can't understand why you would want the bin in the project though but again if you do 1. Import 2. Existing Project - name of workspace 3. Check only the bin otherwise you will duplicate everything.
Hope this helps and works for you.

Comment: Please see my response to @Dave Newton's comment.