# Android Project in Eclipse won't let me access bin folder

Tags: android, eclipse

When I start a new Android project in Eclipse I always get two errors relating to missing the import for Android R. I've asked about it before and I was told that a solution to fix this would involve using my bin folder. However, as well as missing the R import, my project doesn't create a bin folder.

Now, [following an answer given on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643444/how-do-i-make-the-default-bin-directory-visible-in-eclipse) I have done the following to try and generate my bin folder:

1. Right Click your Project, go to Properties.
2. Select Java Build Path from Left Hand Side.
3. On the Right Hand Side, Select Source Tab.
4. Click on Add Folder, and mark the checkbox for bin as SELECTED under Source Folder Selection Window.
5. Press OK and OK again. And you will see your bin Folder.

When I follow those steps, I can get all the way to step 4 but it won't allow me to actually press the final ok button to bring the bin folder into my project.

Is there something that I'm missing in the above steps?

Here is what my project folder set up looks like. Please note this is just a basic project I have create using all default values:

[image]

Comment: The most common source of such problems is that you have something wrong in your resources. And Eclipse is so stupid that it missleads developers in other direction ...

Comment: Don't you mean the `gen` folder?

Comment: Added a screenshot of my folder structure

Comment: Oh.  When you have errors, Eclipse will not auto-build your project.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But to fix the errors I need my bin folder. Which I don't have. Thus my question....

Comment: Uh, dude... The bin folder is what gets generated when it builds your project.

Comment: I've seen videos of people creating new android projects and having the bin folder already in the folder structure :S

Comment: what kind of error you are getting in your main activity.can you post the 'eclipse problem view'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.java` class that is automatically generated when you build.

It is a generated class. If you are using the Android Development Tools (ADT) it is generated whenever the project is built. You may have 'Build Automatically' turned off. Turn it on and build your project.

Your `R.java` may not be generated by many reasons. Some of them are

- Illegal naming of resource in `res` folder.

> only a-z,mind that not capital...and white-space not allowed
>
> name must start with a character.not with a Number(0-9)
>
> name only _ symbol allowed.no other symbol alowed.

- Not all libraries/dependencies included in build path.

> Go into Project=>properties => Java build path= > Order and Export.
>   Please make sure all your jars are checked.

- Malformed XML files i.e. errors in Layouts or Manifest, like missing closing
  tags, useless characters

> Check if all tags etc are closed properly and there are no such errors

- Different SDK being used for compilation, other than that specified
  for compilation in Manifest.

> TargetSDK specified in manifest differs from that specified using
>   project properties dialog.

- Remove any import such as `import android.R`;

> No we don't need default android generated file.

- If you are on ADT 22 you need to add the Android SDK build-tools for Android SDK Manager

> Open SDK manager, check the Android SDK build-tools, and Install

Check every thing, and then clean and rebuild your project.