# How to get the bin folder in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dll, bin

I am searching for the bin folder in eclipse, but I am not able to find it.
I tried this following post, but I am not successful. Please can anyone help me?

[what can I do to make display the bin folder on eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163923/what-can-i-do-to-make-display-the-bin-folder-on-eclipse)

The reason why I am looking for bin folder is, I want to place some .dll files in it. Is there another way of incorporating .dll files? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should not put any data in the bin directory. It gets deleted if you do a `Project` -> `Clean`. Instead you should put your libraries in a `lib` folder. I don't know how you are actually using your dll, but you can surely point to another directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to include this dll only for development purposes, you can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH and include the path for your dlls. I did this in the past with eclipse. There are a location in the CDT eclipse project where you can include this.

If you are speaking about a java aplication that needs a dll, you can add the library in the project also like this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/96304-how-to-add-dll-files-in-javalibrarypath/, but I haven't done it never.