# hibernate.cfg.xml is not exported to executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

When I'am trying to export my project to a executable .jar-file then configuration files like hibernate.cfg.xml or log4j-properties are not exported into the jar. I have to add them manually to the archieve. The files are located in the /target/ folder in the root folder of the project.

How do I get Eclipse to export the config files too?

Comment: How exactly do you generate these `.jar` files?

Comment: @reto Project >> Export >> Java >> Runnable JAR File >> Package required libraries into generated JAR >> Finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a resources folder parallel to your source/src folder, and keep your configuration files in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Eclipse approach:

```
Project >> Export >> Java >> 
Runnable JAR File >> Package required libraries into generated JAR
```

Only the class files get exported in the jar and - if this option is selected - the linked libraries.

You can, however *create an additional source folder* (name it `resources` or `config` or whatever fits your case) and copy your files into this one. This directory will then also be part of your generated jar file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of non-class files not showing up in the exported jar file may be due to Eclipse hiding the output folders.   That is what happened to me.  The problem was that the bin folder for a project my project depended on was hidden by Eclipse. Fixed that by using the Project Explorer to get Eclipse to make the output folder visible.
See [what can I do to make display the bin folder on eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163923/what-can-i-do-to-make-display-the-bin-folder-on-eclipse)

Using Eclipse Oxygen, fixed it by:

```
   -- Selected the project with the hidden output folder in the Project Explorer
   -- Clicked on the triangle in the Project Explorer
   -- Clicked on Filters and Customization
   -- Make sure the Filters Tab is selected.
   -- Uncheck Java Output Folders
```