# How to make the runnable jar file for a maven eclipse project with hibernate configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jar

I tried to make a jar file from my eclipse maven project with hibernate configurations.

This is the structure of my project, I had the file hibernate.cfg.xml in both resources/ and src/main/resources/ folder. And I made the jar file by choosing runnable jar file from export options. (due to the help from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419455/hibernate-cfg-xml-is-not-exported-to-executable-jar))

This is the error I get when running the executable jar file:

```
ehsanik$ java -jar oh_oh.jar 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jvmhub.tutorial.App.StartDB(App.java:25)
    at CopyOfMain.main(CopyOfMain.java:7)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1940)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1921)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1901)
    at com.jvmhub.tutorial.App.StartDB(App.java:19)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR-Solution**

Put your `hibernate.cfg.xml` into `src/main/resource`. Then do not export 
your project by eclipse's export function. Rather use the maven-assembly-plugin to create an executable jar. run with `mvn package assembly:single`.

**What eclipse does and why it is not working**

If you choose "export" in eclipse options, your compiled classes (compiled by eclipse) will be put into that jar. But Eclipse doesn't know anything about the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). It will just leave the files in their folders. Maven, on the other hand, will copy all resources from the `src/main/resources`-folder to the root directory of the jar file.

**How to read the errors you see**

First error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

it means, that log4j did not find a log4j.properties or .xml. It is unconfigured. It is a first hint, that your build was unsucessful.

Second error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

Second hint, that your resources are not in a location where the libraries excpect them to be (hibernate in this case).